# Slice to " "space in python

Tags: python, slice

If  `L = [['abc 1234',2],  ['foo 1',2] ,  ['bar 12312434',2]]`

How would slice L to get everything up to the first space

```
['abc,'foo','bar']
```

Comment: I love these Python speed-codings. They clearly show how fast coding in Python happens in practice. `;)`

Comment: Of course if it's always the three first characters you can use `[i[0][0:3] for i in L]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [1]: L = [['abc 1234',2], ['foo 1',2] , ['bar 12312434',2]]

In [2]: [x[0].split(' ')[0] for x in L]
Out[2]: ['abc', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L = [['abc 1234',2], ['foo 1',2] , ['bar 12312434',2]]
print [x[0].split()[0] for x in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    s = L[i][0]
    s = s.split(' ')[0]
    L[i] = s
```

Comment: Ewwww. Learn list comprehensions, dude!

Comment: @ulidtko Meh, I gave an answer the way I would resort to do it, doesn't mean it has to be accepted or upvoted

Answer (score 0):

In the cases you present, the spaces always occur in the same postion.  If you know this will be the case, you could do something like:

```
L = [['abc 1234',2], ['foo 1',2] , ['bar 12312434',2]]
L2 = [x[0][0:3] for x in L]
print L2
```

Output:

> ['abc', 'foo', 'bar']

Of course, if the spaces can occur in different positions, then you'd be better off using one of the solutions using [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

I find that list comprehensions are sometimes more difficult to read, I would prefer to keep separate the looping and the extraction:

```
def extract(element):
    """Extracts the string until the first space of the first element of a list
    >>> extract(['abc 1234',2])
    'abc'
    """
    return element[0].split()[0]
```

so that you can do some tests on single elements:

```
extract(L[2])
'bar'
```

and then apply this with a list comprehension or using map [applies function to each element of a list]:

```
map(extract,L)
['abc', 'foo', 'bar']
```